# Find a set of linear equations whose solution is the same as the minimum of a given quadratic objective function

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratics

Given an objective function $||x_1 a_1 - x_2 a_2 - b||$, where $a_1, a_2$ and $b$ are 3-dimensional vectors, how can I find the two linear equations for the $x_1$ and $x_2$ whose solution will find such $x_1$ and $x_2$ that the objective function will be minimized?

Comment: hint: Square the norm and find the zero(s) of the gradient.

Comment: Is it not just $(x_1 \mathbf{a_1} - x_2 \mathbf{a_2} - \mathbf{b})\cdot{\mathbf{a_1}} = 0$ and $(x_1 \mathbf{a_1} - x_2 \mathbf{a_2} - \mathbf{b})\cdot{\mathbf{a_2}} = 0$ ?

Comment: @Marconius God, I think you guys are right. It was so simple..

Comment: @Marconius yepp